# Wrong sequence of params in transaction event data (smart contract)

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3py

I am looking at [ethereum trx](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x453a0f0c5a59f01a06ecfc2a91e086ff88663acaaddce132ecca78dcd6070cba#eventlog) at log tab to get event details.
Here is function that was called:

```
BurnConfirmed (index_topic_1 uint256 nonce, index_topic_2 address requester, uint256 amount, string btcDepositAddress, string btcTxid, uint256 timestamp, bytes32 inputRequestHash)
```

from the description, you can see that inputRequestHash is the last param and btcTxid somewhere in the middle.

But when you look at the data:

```
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
```

and decode it, you will get btcTxid instead of inputRequestHash:

```
    print(f"inputRequstHash   : {w3.toText(data[-128:])}")
```

and output:

```
inputRequstHash   : d6648c17064ead28c2a02047bea9172b9b4c9033d294556e356709e9a719d63c
```

that is btcTxid as you can see on EtherScan web site.
How can I be sure that params are on their places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are treated as dynamic-size byte arrays. All dynamic-size arrays are split into at least 3 slots (actually 2 if the array is empty).

- First 32byte slot is a pointer to slot that contains size of the array
- Second slot contains the array size
- Followed by the actual values. They can span across multiple slots if they don't fit into one.

The first slot location always respects the overall order of params. And then the size+values are stored at the end of the payload - after fixed-size types.

```
# slot 0, `amount`
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000746a528800

# slot 1, pointer to location (dec)160 (slot 5) where `btcDepositAddress` size is stored
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0

# slot 2, pointer to location (dec)256 (slot 8) where `btcTxid` size is stored
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100

# slot 3, `timestamp`
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000638a1cf7

# slot 4, `inputRequestHash`
d71eaa8219d43a9ae3659cd0ce3c6d30e4127b810596c00d7c98f6cf717f7177

# slot 5, size of `btcDepositAddress` == (dec)42
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a

# slots 6 and 7, value of `btcDepositAddress`
6263317167656e3833346c73783667397074766c673834333637643865376879
663332647630396a617500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

# slot 8, size of `btcTxid` == (dec)64
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040

# slots 9 and 10, value of `btcTxid`
6436363438633137303634656164323863326130323034376265613931373262
3962346339303333643239343535366533353637303965396137313964363363
```

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types

I could not find any function for decoding event logs in `web3py` but at least here's a link to `web3js` for reference: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.1/web3-eth-abi.html#decodelog